# Back to Ubuntu 20.04 from Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.04, 20.10, versions

I want to go back my Ubuntu 20.04. I updated to Ubuntu 20.10 and I regret it.
Already tried to install again 20.04 from a pendrive, but upon starting the PC it does not recognize the pendrive and 20.10 is launched.

Comment: It sounds like your installation media is invalid.

Comment: Probably need new USB and/or new burn of ISO.  Is your bios set to boot from USB first or manually boot from USB from function key(F12?)?